# Optimal method to add explosions in Spritekit Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have completed a game that was part of my final project which was to make a space Shooter using Xocde and the swift programming language.

I met all the requirements but I wanted to add little stuff here and there just for the fun of it.

I have it to where you control a ship and you must reach a score of 50. Once you hit 50, a Boss will appear that requires 40 hits.

As of right now, once the 40 hits read, then it moves to another gamescene (youwin) scene.

I trying to figure out how to add explosions images on top of the Boss Sprite as the Sprite slowly moves up the screen.

I extracted images from an explosion gif and added them and I would just switch the textures every 0.1 seconds but then I figured thats too much work.

I then tried to use a particle sks already in xcode

```
func explosion(pos: CGPoint) {
      var emitterNode = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "ExplosionParticle.sks")
      emitterNode.particlePosition = pos
      self.addChild(emitterNode)
      // Don't forget to remove the emitter node after the explosion
      self.runAction(SKAction.waitForDuration(2), completion: { emitterNode.removeFromParent() })

  }
```

then

```
If score == 40
{

explosion(self.heroSprite.position)
endGameScene (you win).. etc

}
```

It works but only once...

The explosion happens but it wont follow the bossSprite as it moves up the screen.

My question is, What would be the most optimal way to add explosions to a Sprite once it has reached zero hit points.

The code I provided could be changed a bit to meet my desire I bet but I'm sure it would lag the game and bring the frames down

I have a particle running as the background so I am sure I would experience lag.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Personally I did both of what you've tried and both works just fine. It is up to you to decide / test what works best.

**Animating with Textures**

This just works (using `SKAction.animateWithTextures()`), and it really can't affect on performance if you preload your textures before the game starts. You don't need more than ten textures to make a simple explosion. Just set reasonable time delay when animating and you'll be fine.

**Using SKEmitterNode**

The another solution, which involves `SKEmitterNode` is nice as well. For example, one way I was doing this was by making a property of a desired  emitter on a current scene. Then, you can run an `SKAction` which will add a **copy** of that emitter few times after a certain delay. Important thing here is **to add a copy of an emitter to the boss sprite**. So if it moves, all added emitters will move with it as well. Don't forget to set `zPosition` on an emitter node to be  higher than a boss sprite.

Note that everything really depends on a situation, and sometimes you want a static emitter, and sometimes you want it created per instance of a certain class. But the point is that, if possible (like in this example of yours), after you unarchive the emitter from a disk, you should just re-use it (means, you don't have to unarchive the same emitter multiple times). By doing this, reading from disk is reduced to minimum, and there will be no fps drops. Of course, if you don't use emitters sparingly, there is always a chances for some lag. Also removing an emitter when it is done with emitting is a good practice according to the docs, so don't forget to do that either.